# GParted - Cannot open display

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I just installed gparted because I have a 135 GB flash drive that I want to use for bootables for different OSs.

After I installed `gparted` and opened it from the Dash, I got the prompt for my password, entered it, the window closed, cursor turned to the loading symbol, I waited, the cursor went back to normal, that was it.

I installed it with `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

The output from `gksudo gparted` is

```
Error copying '/home/amolith/.Xauthority' to '/tmp/libgksu-k9KFpI': No such file or directory
```

The output from `gparted-pkexec` is

```
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/boot.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-120.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/snap-core-2381.mount → /dev/null.


Created symlink /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:6347): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Removed /run/systemd/system/-.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/boot.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-120.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/snap-core-2381.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a terminal run `gksudo gparted` or `gparted-pkexec` enter your password see what happens what output do you get ?

Comment: @Ravexina The output from both commands is in the question now.

Comment: Seems related to Wayland, run `xhost +local:` then `gparted-pkexec`.

Comment: @Ravexina That fixed it! What does `xhost +local:` do?

Comment: @Amolith `man xhost` explains clearly:  *The  xhost  program is used to add and delete host names or user names to the list allowed to make connections to the X server.* And option `+local:` means grant access (`+`) for `local` family of users/addressese etc., and empty string member, thus `:` at the end.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your problem seems related to the wayland, run:

```
xhost +local:
```

it lets local users to connect to the display, then run gparted:

```
gparted-pkexec
```

it should solve the problem.

[source](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=17446)

Comment: could you give more specific info for wayland pls @Ravexina.. as i know it is an alternative server of XORG

Comment: @solfish I'm not really familiar with Wayland but I think it's because of the way it controls display/window permissions, some incomparability between package and Wayland might be the cause of issue. [similar](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218175) question.

Comment: While this fixes issue, this seems to be not **persistent**. Any idea of how to make it **persistent** after reboot?

Comment: @PeterM Put the command somewhere like `~/.profile`, it should get run automatically every time Ubuntu get started ;)

Comment: the xhost command solved my problem. After executing that I am able to run gparted normally. Thank you very much.

Comment: The actual comment that helped me:
xhost +SI:localuser:root

Comment: I don't know for what reason I can't add my answer to this thread (I just don't see such a button on stackoverflow), but actually it looks like solution is to run the command "sudo xhost +" without "local" at the end.  It has nothing to do with gparted: this happens as you run in vnc session any gui app under sudo.

Comment: as @IhorB. pointed out this issues happens when doing a remote session where a "display" is created.  It is not just vnc but any remote session software that needs to create a display like nomachine which I use.  If there is already a login/display on the machine because some is directly on it and then you attach to that "local" display then this issue won't occur, but if you are connecting to a headless machine a display will need to be created and that's when this issue occurs and is resolved by the xhost command.