# gparted asks for permission then does nothing

Tags: permissions, gparted

Title, when I try to run it from terminal it says this after asking for permission.

```
$ gparted
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway. /usr/sbin/gpartedbin:
error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

First day using linux, what does this mean? 
I thought it meant I was missing something so I tried to download it, it put out:

```
$ sudo apt install gparted
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gparted is already the newest version (0.30.0-3ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt install --reinstall gparted
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/505 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 192326 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gparted_0.30.0-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking gparted (0.30.0-3ubuntu2) over (0.30.0-3ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up gparted (0.30.0-3ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to find anything on the internet that fixes this problem. Running Xubuntu 18.04.3, so I don't have other ways to format my usb.

Comment: You can always try to reinstall `gparted` by running `sudo apt install --reinstall gparted` from a terminal window.

Comment: It means that this library is not installed, or has been corrupted. Do you have the package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 installed?

Comment: @Terrance I just did that and I get the same error when I try to run it.

Comment: Update: I think I do have it installed. I tried to install it and this is what it said.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is already the newest version (1:2.24.5-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Please have a look at this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1726545 and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10 and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/939938/gparted-cannot-open-display

Comment: How would I know if I'm using wayland? The only option I have is 'Xubuntu session' and 'Xfce' Is Xubuntu Wayland? 
Gpart doesn't work regardless of which one I choose.  @Raffa

'xhost si:localuser:root' doesn't help either, gpart still refuses to open.

Comment: Xubuntu does not use Wayland for its default DE it uses X, so no worries there since Xfce4 is written for X.org.  You can also try reinstalling `libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` with the same command as above.  Maybe also try `sudo ldconfig` so it might try to fix lib files.  I am not experiencing the same errors as you so I can only guess here.

Comment: Edited! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` and check if the problem is solved then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GParted not working error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691672/gparted-not-working-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtkmm-2-4-so-1)

Comment: @KristopherIves the solution in the linked Possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/a/691681/968501 suggests installing `ubuntu-desktop` which will change the login manager and the desktop environment completely. OP is using xubuntu with xfce desktop.

Comment: I ended up reinstall xubuntu and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

identify missing libaries with `ldd /usr/sbin/gpartedbin | grep not`

You can find the  packages with `apt-file search string of missing libary.`  You have to install it first

```
sudo apt install apt-file && sudo apt update
```

Example

```
apt-file search libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1.1.0
```